# Why is Kafka consumer still consuming messages after the message retention period is set to zero

Tags: c#, apache-kafka

I have a Kafka cluster set up in Confluent Cloud with numerous topics and consumers reading messages from these different topics. The consumers are C# Dotnet applications hosted in GCP/GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine), that are configured to run forever.

I would like the ability to flush/purge a topic of my choosing at any given moment, so I have written a script to automate this with Confluent CLI by setting the message retention period (retention.ms) to 0, waiting until the operation has completed, reverting the retention period back to it's original value.

This works fine if I purge the topic before spinning up the consumer, but if the consumer is already running before the retention period is set to 0 then it keeps reading messages until it is restarted. I need to be able to purge the topic without killing the consumer.

How do I prevent the consumers from continuing to pick up messages when I want to flush the topic and why is this happening in the first place? Are there some additional configurations that need to be set?

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, you can't, not from the consumer.

Only closed segments are deleted, not records on the broker. And the log cleaner runs on an interval of its own, not immediately when you modify any config.

As long as there's an open/active segment, you'll get events...

I'm not sure your exact use case, but deleting topics and using a unique name would work better (consumers can subscribe to a regex, so you don't need to provide an exact, static name), or better tracking of offset information such that you can precisely seek a consumer within an existing topic where you want to read from. For example, use a ProducerCallback to commit the lowest offset per batch of data you're trying to read